# Install spyder-vim in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, vim, anaconda, spyder

When I try to install spyder-vim in ubuntu 18.04 like this page instructed [spyder-vim](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-vim):
The command I use is:

```
conda install spyder-vim -c spyder-ide
```

However, it is not working, the error message is :

> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - spyder-vim
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/spyder-ide/linux-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/spyder-ide/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

After that, I try to search the channel of spyder-vim in anaconda.org. There is no channel of spyder-vim. I am not sure, is there any other way to install it?
Thanks for your reply. ^_^

Answer (score 6):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately `spyder-vim` has not been officially released and the instructions in its Readme are outdated.

Also, we don't have the resources to finish this project right now (maybe in 2019, but we can't make promises about it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also thanks for your contributions to spyder development.

Answer (score 2):

As Spyder maintainer @Carlos Cordoba has mentioned in his answer, `spyder-vim` has not yet been officially released.

Having said this, I installed the `spyder-vim` (*development*) plugin some time ago and it seems stable enough. Not all of the vim keybindings are implemented, but the most basic ones are. Still, though, I'm happy with this plugin.

If you wish, you can install the *development* branch of the plugin with:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder.vim.git
```

You'll need to restart any spyder sessions to use this plugin.

Though I'm pretty sure this plugin will work in spyder3, I'm actually currently running it in the beta release of spyder4 (which you can get with `pip install --pre -U spyder`)

Comment: I gave the command you suggest and restarted Spyder, and the whole Anaconda Navigator, but on restart I don't have the vim keybindings. Do I have to do something else to activate them?  Spyder version: 3.3.6;